# Validating unknown input fields in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to validate a form I have created. The form I have looks something like this:

```
<input id="box-1-nickname" name="box-1-nickname" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Required">

<select id="box-1-destination" name="box-1-destination" class="form-control">
    <option value="store">Storage Facility</option>
    <option value="ship">Ship</option>
</select>

<input class="box-height form-control" id="box-1-height" name="box-1-height" type="number" placeholder="in Inches">
<input class="box-width form-control" id="box-1-width" name="box-1-width" type="number" placeholder="in Inches">
<input class="box-depth form-control" id="box-1-depth" name="box-1-depth" type="number" placeholder="in Inches">
<input class="box-weight form-control" id="box-1-weight" name="box-1-weight" type="number" placeholder="in Pounds">

<label class="radio-inline">
    <input id="box-1-size-retail" name="box-1-size" type="radio" value="retail" checked>
    Retail box (18" x 18" x 22")
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input id="box-1-size-custom" name="box-1-size" type="radio" value="custom">
    I'll use my own box
</label>
```

The part that complicates it a bit is the fact that a user can 'add a box' which will duplicate these form fields and increment the box ID by 1. After adding/removing a few boxes and submitting the form the `Input::all()` might come back looking something like this:

```
array (size=29)
  'box-1-nickname' => string 'Something' (length=9)
  'box-1-destination' => string 'store' (length=5)
  'box-1-height' => string '1' (length=1)
  'box-1-width' => string '2' (length=1)
  'box-1-depth' => string '3' (length=1)
  'box-1-weight' => string '4' (length=1)
  'box-1-size' => string 'retail' (length=9)
  'box-4-nickname' => string 'Another' (length=7)
  'box-4-destination' => string 'ship' (length=4)
  'box-4-height' => string '33' (length=2)
  'box-4-width' => string '1' (length=1)
  'box-4-depth' => string '22' (length=2)
  'box-4-weight' => string '33' (length=2)
  'box-4-size' => string 'custom' (length=6)
  'box-6-nickname' => string 'Stuff' (length=5)
  'box-6-destination' => string 'store' (length=5)
  'box-6-height' => string '34' (length=2)
  'box-6-width' => string '76' (length=2)
  'box-6-depth' => string '44' (length=2)
  'box-6-weight' => string '2' (length=1)
  'box-6-size' => string 'retail' (length=9)
  'box-8-nickname' => string 'Things and others' (length=17)
  'box-8-destination' => string 'ship' (length=4)
  'box-8-height' => string '5' (length=1)
  'box-8-width' => string '66' (length=2)
  'box-8-depth' => string '5' (length=1)
  'box-8-weight' => string '33' (length=2)
  'box-8-size' => string 'custom' (length=6)
  '_token' => string 'BIXSdz16ccJLaOmTxh2ShW5C16W1g0xmpJ10xnwC' (length=40)
```

I'm struggling to find a way to validate these box inputs since I don't really know how many box fields would be submitted or what their input names would be. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the names of your input variables might be the way to go here. Instead of having `box-1-...` and `box-2-...` etc, why not have names like this:

```
name="box-nickname[]"
name="box-destination[]"
name="box-height[]"
name="box-width[]"
name="box-depth[]"
name="box-weight[]"
```

If you had 2 of these boxes sent to the server, calling `Input::all()` would look something like this:

```
'box-nickname' => array(
  "0" => "Value of Box Nickname 1",
  "1" => "Value of Box Nickname 2",
  ...),
'box-destination' => array(
  "0" => "Value of Box Destination 1",
 ...
```

You get the idea right? Validating this becomes simple, the rules only need to be applied to each array of values, and not every numerical box sent:

```
$rules = array(
  "box-nickname" => "Required|Max:6",
  "box-destination" => "Required|Numeric"
  ...
);
```

And you can change the rules to whatever you would like. The only difficult part to this is displaying validator messages on redirecting back to the page. Therefore, I would also recommend pairing this with client-side validation, which handles dynamically generated inputs better than Laravel can when using `Redirect::to()->withInput()->withErrors($validator)`.

Hope that provided some insight to your issues!

Comment: Thanks this work great, however on my radio inputs there seems to be some trouble. I tried something like `<input id="box-1-size-retail" name="box-size[]" type="radio" value="retail" checked>` but all the boxes seem to share the inputs and I can only choose one 'box-size' instead of one per box.

Comment: Ah yes, the good old radio buttons... For this example, consider switching them to a `<select>` with `<option value="*">`, where * would be replaced with your sizes, and this will work. The trouble with radio buttons is that they are inherently an array-like input.